# Add custom elements to metadata generator

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I'm generating metadata.xml using `org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator`

`MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata);`

The identity provider (idp) needs to have attributes specific to that idp.
I don't see any way to add custom attributes to the metadata generator.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to extend the MetadataGenerator. The good candidate methods to override are `buildSPSSODescriptor` and `buildExtensions`.

Comment: Something like this? 

```Extensions extensions = super.buildExtensions(entityBaseURL, entityAlias);

extensions.getUnknownXMLObjects().add(object);```

If so, then should I extend particular abstract class that implements XMLObject? Would org.opensaml.xml.AbstractXMLObject be correct?

Comment: Here is an example file of the metadata which contains custom attributes: http://esuomi.fi/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/metadata.xml

Comment: For adding ContactPerson, is this the only way?
    public EntityDescriptor generateMetadata() {
        EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor = super.generateMetadata();
        ContactPersonBuilder builder = new ContactPersonBuilder();
        ContactPerson contactPerson = builder.buildObject();
        SurNameBuilder build = new SurNameBuilder();
        SurName surName = build.buildObject();
        surName.setName("My surname");
        contactPerson.setSurName(surName);
        entityDescriptor.getContactPersons().add(contactPerson);
        return entityDescriptor;
    }

Comment: Yes, I believe it's the only way at the moment.